# VB6 Controls appearing transparent over UserControl Frame

Tags: user-controls, vb6, transparent, visible, ocx

I have some VB6 controls that I have placed on a frame OCX that I have created myself. The issue, is when the frames are made visible, sometimes the controls (in this example 2 comboboxes) are missing, and you can see the background color of the Form through it.

The Usercontrol, is just 2 images with gradients, and a label for the title.

Are there any settings for UserControls that I need to know about that will fix this?

[image]

**EDITED**

AutoRedraw: True
Clip Controls: True

Comment: What are your AutoRedraw and ClipCOntrols properties set to in your custom frame?

Comment: @tcarvin Edited, Both are true.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been busy.  Are the comboboxes custom as well of standard VB6 once?  Is your frame next in other controls that have non-default AutoRedraw or ClipControl setting?  If you drag the form do the comboboxes get refreshed?  If you cover them with another windows and then reveal them, do they get refreshed?

Comment: How are the images displayed? Image control? PictureBox? PaintPicture? Actually, can you supply a bit more information about how this is all layed out?

Comment: And why have you tagged this with "transparent"? Are you saying that you deliberately use transparency as part of the GUI?

Comment: Actually, some simplified repro case wouldn't go amiss here.

Comment: Come on! I want to help, but you have given hardly any information at all. Create a repro case with the simplest amount of code possible that shows this problem. I bet you'd fix your own problem by doing this!

Comment: Any luck here or are you still struggling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clip Controls had to be set to False. Fixed me whole problem. Thanks for the answers though

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that your container usercontrol have AutoRedraw=true and ClipControls=true

2) Add the following code to your container usercontrol:

```
Private Sub UserControl_Paint()
   Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: With AutoRedraw set to True, you should not get a Paint event.

Answer (score 0):

Set your background images as

`backgroundimage.zorder 1`

And your controls

`combobox1.zorder 0`

You can do this at runtime.  I think your combo boxes are pushed back behind your image in the Z-Order.  This is similar to the "Bring to front" and "push to back" options you have at design time.

Comment: Man up if you're going to downvote and at least post why you're doing it.  It could at least help the OP or myself understand why.  I had this EXACT problem before with controls and it was the Z-Order!